# Numerical invariants for a graph or its complement that are bounded by some constant

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm looking for numerical graph invariants that are bounded by a constant either for a graph $G$ or its complement $\bar{G}$.  (The complement graph $\bar{G}$ has the same set of vertices as $G$ but the edges are complemented.)  More specifically I’m looking for what numerical “Invariant $X$” is out there for which the following statement is true:

“Invariant $X$ is bounded by a constant $c$ either for $G$ or $\bar{G}$”.

One example is diameter $d(G)$ of a graph $G$ where it is known that:

"Either $d(G) \leq 3$ or $d(\bar{G}) \leq 3$"

(Reference: F. Harary, R. W. Robinson: The diameter of a graph and its complement , The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 92, No. 3. (Mar., 1985), pp. 211-212”)

My question  is what other such numerical graph invariants are out there? I looked at the list of [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Graph_invariants) on wikipedia but there was no mention of such bound on their respective pages.
 Again, all I’m interested is that the condition holds for either $G$ or its complement $\bar{G}$ and not necessarily for both.

Comment: what about (the number of generators) of graph homology or cohomology?Or C* algebraic invariants of the corresponding "graph c* algebras"?

Comment: @AliTaghavi The number of generators for the homology group of $G$ is $|E(G)|-|V(G|+1$, so this will be big for either $G$ or $\overline{G}$.

Comment: Well, I should've signed up to mathoverflow before asking the question :) Now I cannot reply to individual comments or accept an answer (because of the 50 reputation score limitation - which is a good thing to eliminate spam). So I'm posting this: - Tony: Thanks for the two examples and spending effort for a proof. - David: Yours is my favorite among all. Especially the connection to Ramsey's theorem is quite interesting. Thank you! - Shahrooz: I was asking for "upper" bounds as Gordon also commented. Thanks for spending time on it.

Answer (score 8):

Let $c(G)$ be the number of connected components of $G$.  Then for all graphs $G$,
$$
c(G)=1 \text{ or } c(\overline{G})=1. 
$$

Here is a slightly more interesting family of examples. For a fixed integer $k$, define $d_k(G)$ to be the number of degree-$k$ vertices of $G$.

**Claim.**
For all graphs $G$, 
$$d_k(G) \leq 2k \text{ or } d_k(\overline{G}) \leq 2k.
$$

**Proof.** Suppose that $G$ contains more than $2k$ degree-$k$ vertices.  Let $X$ be a set of degree-$k$ vertices of $G$ with $|X|=2k+1$.  Let $N_G(X)$ be the neighbours of $X$ in $G$.  Let $Y$ be the set of degree-$k$ vertices in $\overline{G}$.  Since the vertices in $V(G) \setminus N_G(X)$ are not adjacent to any vertex in $X$, it follows that $Y \subseteq N_G(X)$.  Towards a contradiction, suppose $|Y| \geq 2k+1$.  Since $|X|=2k+1$, each vertex in $Y$ must send at least $k+1$ edges (in $G$) to $X$.  Thus, there are at least $(2k+1)(k+1)$ edges between $N_G(X)$ and $X$.  On the other hand, the number of edges between $X$ and $N_G(X)$ is at most $k|X|=k(2k+1)$, so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Another one: girth. By Ramsey's theorem, for every graph $G$ on six or more vertices, either it or its complement has girth at most three.

Comment: Nice one. +1ed.  It is a bit funny that girth is usually defined to be $\infty$ for acyclic graphs, and there are obviously small graphs $G$ such that $G$ and $\overline{G}$ are both acyclic.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of properties which $G$ and $\overline{G}$ both have them: number of vertices (edges), automorphism group, and etc. So, naturally this question is interesting for me. I want to mention a spectral property. Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices, and $\rho(G)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of $G$. Then we have:
$$\rho(G)\geq \frac{n-1}{2}\; \; \text{or}\;\; \rho(\overline{G})\geq \frac{n-1}{2}.$$

I will give the simplified proof for the above fact.

For any $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, we have:
$$\lambda_i(A+B)\leq \lambda_j(A)+\lambda_{i-j+1}(B),\;\; n\geq i\geq j\geq 1,$$
where, $\lambda_i(A)$ denotes the $i$th greatest eigenvalue of the matrix $A$. Now, for graph $G$, let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$ and $B$ be the adjacency matrix of $\overline{G}$. Since we have $A+B=J-I$, which is the adjacency matrix of complete graph, the result is clear.

Comment: I think the OP is after constant upper bounds.